# Prometheus histogram get number of requests per bucket

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

We have a histogram bucket (myapp_duration_seconds_bucket) with different le values that captures the response time of an api.
From this I would like to find the count of requests per bucket using Prometheus query.

For example below is Prometheus output for bucket myapp_duration_seconds_bucket by le. The histogram buckets are cumulative, but I would like to get the count per bucket to find the exact number of transactions that fall into each bucket.

- le="+Inf"    8229
- le="0.005"   0
- le="0.01"    0
- le="0.025"   0
- le="0.05"    5149
- le="0.075"   7101
- le="0.1"     7466
- le="0.25"    7942
- le="0.5"   8070
- le="0.75"    8120
- le="1.0" 8156
- le="10.0"    8229
- le="2.5" 8223
- le="5.0" 8229
- le="7.5" 8229
- le="0.1" 7466
- le="0.25"    7942
- le="0.5" 8070
- le="0.75"    8120
- le="1.0" 8156
- le="10.0"    8229
- le="2.5" 8223
- le="5.0" 8229
- le="7.5" 8229

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a PromQL query, which could return per-bucket hits for Prometheus [histograms](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) with arbitrary number of buckets. But you can calculate the number of hits for a particular bucket by using the following query:

```
myapp_duration_seconds_bucket{le="UPPER_BOUND"}
  - ignoring(le)
myapp_duration_seconds_bucket{le="LOWER_BOUND"}
```

This query would return the number of hits for the bucket with `(LOWER BOUND ... UPPER_BOUND]` boundaries. Note that `UPPER_BOUND` and `LOWER_BOUND` must exist in `le` label values for the `myapp_duration_seconds_bucket` metric.

The query uses `ignoring()` modifier for ignoring the `le` label when calculating the difference between distinct time series with distinct `le` label values. See more details about this [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

P.S. Take a look at [VictoriaMetrics histograms](https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350) - their buckets already contain the exact number of hits per each bucket, so there is no need in additional calculations there.